# ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 - Signed LogoutRequest using POST

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

With reference to our [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73915345/itfoxtec-identity-saml-2-0-signed-logoutrequest-failing) our customer asked us to change the SamlIdpSettings:logouturl setting to:

```
https://idpqa.csu.edu.au/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SLO
```

but the following then occurred:

```
2022-10-17 09:51:12,555 - 137.166.20.125 - ERROR [org.opensaml.profile.action.impl.DecodeMessage:73] - Profile Action DecodeMessage: Unable to decode incoming request
org.opensaml.messaging.decoder.MessageDecodingException: This message decoder only supports the HTTP POST method
        at org.opensaml.saml.saml2.binding.decoding.impl.HTTPPostDecoder.doDecode(HTTPPostDecoder.java:84)
2022-10-17 09:51:12,556 - 137.166.20.125 - WARN [org.opensaml.profile.action.impl.LogEvent:101] - A non-proceed event occurred while processing the request: UnableToDecode
```

How can we change our code to use a POST request instead of a GET when sending the logout request?

Answer (score 0):

The TestWebAppCore sample do logout using `POST` with the `Saml2PostBinding`.
It can be change to use `GET` by using the `Saml2RedirectBinding`.

- https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L68
- https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L81
- https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L90